# OpenACC - Nested loop strange behaviour

Tags: c++, nested-loops, openacc

I'm working on [LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) of [block diagonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices) using OpenACC.
I get the correct decomposition when I run my code sequentially, whilst when executing it under OpecACC directives I get wrong result when conducting the decomposition.

LU decomposition involves nested loop of that type (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#C_code_examples) `LUPSolve` function):

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   for (unsigned int k = 0; k < i; k++)
```

It appears that when this type of nested loop is used in a `routine seq` directive within a parallel region, the device always manages to enter the nested loop *even when* `i=0` (which souldn't be possible because of the `k<i` condition).

I made a simple code to check it:

```
#pragma acc routine seq
void test ( int* x, int const n ) {
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      x[i] = -1;
      for (unsigned int k = 0; k < i; k++)
         x[i] = k < i;
   }
}

int main ( ) {
   unsigned const n(4);
   unsigned const nb(3);
   int x[nb*n];
   #pragma acc parallel loop copyout(x[:nb*n])
   for (unsigned int b = 0; b < nb; b++)
      test(x+b*n,n);
   // display x
}
```

The result I get is this one:

```
x = 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
```

But the correct one (which I get when I run the code without OpenACC) should be:

```
x = -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1,
```

I must be doing something wrong because it shouldn't enter the nested loop when `i=0`...
Plus when I put the loops directly in the parallel region (without using a function call) it does work fine.

Comment: It's very strange, I tried also with nested loop of this type:
`for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) { for (int k = i+1; k < n; k++) }`
And the device doesn't enter the nested loop for `i=n-1` but if I change this into:
`for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) { for (int k = 0; k < n-i-1; k++) }`
The same strange behaviour happens and the device enters the nested loop for `i=n-1`... It's like `0<0` is true for nested loop... I just don't know what I'm doing wrong, it must be somewhere in my loop's condition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a compiler code generator issue where it's always executing the inner loop even when k and i are both zero.  I've filed a problem report (TPR#24317) and sent it to our compiler engineers for further evaluation.  As a work-around, add an "if" check in the inner loop.

```
% cat test.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#pragma acc routine seq
void test ( int* x, int const n ) {
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      x[i] = -1;
      for (unsigned int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
         if (k < i)
            x[i] = (k<i);
      }
   }
}

int main ( ) {
   unsigned const n(4);
   unsigned const nb(3);
   int x[nb*n];
   #pragma acc parallel loop copyout(x[:nb*n])
   for (unsigned int b = 0; b < nb; b++)
      test(x+b*n,n);

   for (int i=0; i <nb; ++i) {
   for (int j=0; j <n; ++j) {
     printf("%d:%d %d\n", i,j, x[i*n+j]);
  } }
   exit(0);
}
% pgc++ -acc -Minfo=acc -ta=tesla:cc60 test.cpp; a.out
test(int *, int):
      5, Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
main:
     18, Generating copyout(x[:])
         Accelerator kernel generated
         Generating Tesla code
         20, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(3) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
0:0 -1
0:1 1
0:2 1
0:3 1
1:0 -1
1:1 1
1:2 1
1:3 1
2:0 -1
2:1 1
2:2 1
2:3 1
```

Comment: Thank you I was going crazy! I ended up with an `if` check as well

Comment: FYI, the original issue (TPR#24317) was fixed in PGI release 19.1